# Pass a hash to ActiveRecord#save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a an `after_save` callback on `Scorecard` class.

In this callback I create and save an object in a different model `BalanceLedger`.

I need to pass a message to this object being created in the `after_save` of `Scorecard`

Is this possible?

e.g. (where this is not valid but trying to get my point across)

```
scorecard.total = new_total
scorecard.save(message: 'This is an Admin correction')

class Scorecard < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_save do
    BalanceLedger.create!(total: total, message: params[:message])
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use `:attr_accessor` to set a virtual attribute? You could set a `message` value, and retrieve it from within the callback.

```
scorecard.total = new_total
scorecard.message = 'This is an Admin correction'
scorecard.save

class Scorecard < ActiveRecord::Base    
  attr_accessor :message 

  after_save do
    BalanceLedger.create!(total: total, message: message)
  end
end
```

Comment: I like this thought. Let me look into this.